# make file error, trying to install intel power gadget

Tags: 13.10, make, c

I hope another Ubuntu user has tried to run Intel power gadget and knows what problem I am having.

I am trying to install the power gadget, running the make file i get an error message:

```
/usr/lib/power_gadget/rapl.c:516: undefined reference to `log'
```

This line refers to the line in a .c file:

```
return (log((double)(time / RAPL_TIME_UNIT)) - A_LNF[F]) / LN2;
```

Is this log function being called correctly?
Am I missing a dependency on my Ubuntu setup?
Is there perhaps a missing library file in my download?

Thanks in advance for any help

Regards

Roz

Edit, the make file is below:

```
CFLAGS=-g

all: rapl_lib_shared rapl_lib_static power_gadget_static

rapl_lib_shared: 
    gcc $(CFLAGS) -fpic -c msr.c cpuid.c rapl.c 
    gcc $(CFLAGS) -shared -o librapl.so msr.o cpuid.o rapl.o

rapl_lib_static: 
    gcc $(CFLAGS) -c msr.c cpuid.c rapl.c 
    ar rcs librapl.a msr.o cpuid.o rapl.o

power_gadget_static: 
    gcc $(CFLAGS) power_gadget.c -I. -L. -lm -o power_gadget ./librapl.a

power_gadget: 
    gcc $(CFLAGS) power_gadget.c -I. -L. -lm -lrapl -o power_gadget 

gprof: CFLAGS = -pg
gprof: all
    ./power_gadget -e 100 -d 60 >/dev/null 2>&1
    gprof power_gadget > power_gadget.gprof
    rm -f gmon.out
    make clean

clean: 
    rm -f power_gadget librapl.so librapl.a msr.o cpuid.o rapl.o
```

Comment: Can you point us how this file is compiled? Perhaps there is an error in the makefile: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9145264/undefined-reference-to-log

Answer (score 7):

I got the same problem and managed to solve it by simply change the `-lm` flag to the end off the GCC command.

So the Makefile now looks like this:

```
CFLAGS=-g

all: rapl_lib_shared rapl_lib_static power_gadget_static

rapl_lib_shared: 
gcc $(CFLAGS) -fpic -c msr.c cpuid.c rapl.c
gcc $(CFLAGS) -shared -o librapl.so msr.o cpuid.o rapl.o

rapl_lib_static:
gcc $(CFLAGS) -c msr.c cpuid.c rapl.c
ar rcs librapl.a msr.o cpuid.o rapl.o

power_gadget_static: 
gcc $(CFLAGS) power_gadget.c -I. -L. -o power_gadget ./librapl.a -lm

power_gadget:
gcc $(CFLAGS) power_gadget.c -I. -L. -lrapl -o power_gadget -lm

gprof: CFLAGS = -pg
gprof: all
./power_gadget -e 100 -d 60 >/dev/null 2>&1
gprof power_gadget > power_gadget.gprof
rm -f gmon.out
make clean

clean:
rm -f power_gadget librapl.so librapl.a msr.o cpuid.o rapl.o
```