# How to measure power using Intel Power Gadget on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: power-management

I could install power_gadget taking help from this post [make file error, trying to install intel power gadget](https://askubuntu.com/questions/415016/make-file-error-trying-to-install-intel-power-gadget)

but whenever I'm trying to use it as ./power_gadget [-e [sampling_delay_ms ] optional] -d duration]
I get the error that 
RAPL not supported or machine model 506e3 not recognized
Can anybody tell me how to fix this ?

Comment: What CPU do you have? Not all CPUs have the option to run intel power gadget

Comment: I am using intel i7- 6700 processor (SkyLake). yeah it seems so

Comment: So it should work. Skylake supports power reading. Do you need the power meter specifically, or do you need some way to get a power reading?

Comment: I just need to get the power reading somehow. Is there a way?

Comment: I can recommend trying to use a software I helped creating that does that.  I have posted it in an answer.

Answer (score 4):

I can recommend an alternative. It is a program we have been working on called s-tui. It shows, it part, the power usage of the CPU if your CPU supports it (Intel CPUs 2nd Core gen and newer).
Installation is explained on the github page [s-tui on github](https://github.com/amanusk/s-tui)

Here is a screenshot of what it looks like: 
[image]

Comment: Okay I can try this

Comment: I'm using Intel i7-6700, but power and temperature readings  are not coming. What might be the reason?

Comment: This can only work if Ubuntu runs natively on your computer. It will not work if Ubuntu runs in a Virtual Machine with Windows as a host. You can try running a portable version of Ubuntu from a USB stick without installing to get the results. If you have been running Intel Power Gadget on a VM, it could also be the reason why it does not work.

Comment: Oh I see, I'll install ubuntu on native computer , check and let you know. I think Intel power Gadget doesn't support my processor. That was the scenario few years back, as I found from other forum posts and news. I was just wondering if things have changed for better now

Answer (score -1):

[image]

It shows utilization and frequency but power and temperature are not there